# How to statically link library with JVM

Tags: java, android, c++, jvm, java-native-interface

Q1. How to statically link library with JVM.  I need to call C code (.a file) from Java application using JNI.  The .a file has to be statically linked with JVM before use.  I am using eclipse as an IDE.  I am able to link the .so file (i.e. dynamic library) as native lib with the jdk1.8  [way to link dynamic library with JVM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FD0eR.png) ?
_
Q2. Also Code and configuration for how to make a call from 
JAVA class to C statically link library using JNI in JDK 1.8?

Comment: Android does not use the JVM.

Comment: It's needed to rebuild your static *.a library into a static one *.so and use it

Comment: As per JDK 8 docs,  A native library may be statically linked with the VM. Can anyone explain how ?

Comment: Could you provide a link where it says "A native library may be statically linked with the VM"?

Comment: The "VM" is itself a library. The "java" executable just *uses* this library. You can always create your own executable and link the VM and your own library in it. But try cdovgal's suggestion first. Is easier but might not work dependending on compiler flags used when building the static library.

Comment: @manuell Take a glance at JEP 178 for example: https://openjdk.org/jeps/178 Also JNI Specification Chapter 2: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html Also, a simple websearch on "A native library may be statically linked with the VM." turned up 3 results for me: the 2 official sources I listed in this comment and this very question.